# Asp.Net. Change routing if query parameter exists

Tags: asp.net-core

Say I have two different actions and only one parameter in query determinate which action should be used. For example if I have request like that

```
https://localhost:44386/controller?foo=1&bar=1&myparam=1
```

I want to use action

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task MyAction([FromQuery] int myparam, [FromQuery] FooBarDto dto)
```

And in that case

```
https://localhost:44386/controller?foo=1&bar=1
```

I want to use

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task MyAction2([FromQuery] FooBarDto dto)
```

Obviously I can use something like `Controller.RedirectToAction()` but I don't want to return anything from my actions.

Also I can use something like this

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task MyAction([FromQuery] int myparam, [FromQuery] FooBarDto dto)
{
    if (leveling > 0)
    {
        await MyAction2(dto);
        return;
    }
    // other business logic here
}
```

But maybe there is some more pleasant way exists?

Comment: Routing decides where your request ends up, parameters decide what your method does. Have you tried searching for how to combine that? See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53620779/route-to-controller-based-on-query-string

Comment: Looks interesting, I should try it, thanks

Comment: Upd: works just fine for me!